# TextMate for Java/Maven development

Tags: java, macos, ide, textmate, textmatebundles

Is anybody doing Java/Maven development with TextMate? Any Bundle I can use for it? I am aware of regular bundles for Maven and Java (to generate part of the code), but are there are any bundles to help list classes methods? (like Eclipse/Netbeans/etc. does). And not the *current* class methods, but say I have FirstDemo.java which has methods demo(String a) and demoThis(String a, int b).

In SecondDemo.java I want to type new FirstDemo().[click something here] and see list of demo(String a) and demoThis(String a, int b) so I can choose from them.

Any chance I can do something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Now there is: https://github.com/textmate/maven.tmbundle

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you want something more sophisticated, you'll need a real IDE or JEdit with some plugins.